# Redirect to LoginPage using tiles in Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, tiles-3

I have a problem in the handler of my application, i'm using Spring Security, Tiles, but i can't do the redirect to the login from template that use tiles.
I think my problem is here:

```
<bean id="viewResolvers" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Please help me to do the integration correctly between Spring MVC, Tiles and Spring Security.

Comment: hi, do you have a tiles viewresolver, too?

Comment: No, i don't have another view resolver.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in you security xml file, there is a configuaration in this file when you need to do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

you need a viewresolver for Tiles. And you have to set the order of the viewResolvers.

```
<bean id="viewResolvers" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
     <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="0"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>
```